# Creating an autoclick system in a sketchware app

Tags: automation, sketchware

Me and my friend are creating an app in sketchware and we need a system similar to an autoclick to make some grips on the screen

We tried some codes and blocks, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code

```
yourView.performClick();
```